# Why my camera can write images to micro sd card but my computer can not?

Tags: sd-card

I have a micro sd card and a sd card adapter. The problem is I can't delete, create new file or format the card with my computer (it says the disk is write-protected), however when I use the card in my DSLR and it actually takes images and writes them to the card. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: This is 100% a valid question and the answer is likely this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FiIN0KtBJ_M/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: @Sickest I toggled the switch hundred times and trust me it's kind of dead and only readable but the problem is why a camera could still write images onto it.